# NSMutableArray unable to add static NSString, throws exception

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray

An NSMutableArray was created with 64 capacity. A NSString object was added. However, string value of the object is nil.

```
static NSString* cake = @"cake"; 
...
NSMutableArray* food = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:64];
[food addObject:[NSString stringWithString:cake]];
NSString* dessert = [[food objectAtIndex:0]stringValue];
// dessert is nil
```

if `[NSString stringWithString: cake]` is replaced with just `cake`, it throws an exception

Here is an entire program which is less than 10 lines of code and does not work

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
static NSString* cake = @"cake";
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSMutableArray* food = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:64];
        [food addObject:cake];
        NSString* dessert = [[food objectAtIndex:0]stringValue];
    }
}
```

It throws an exception.

Comment: >> [[food objectAtIndex:0]stringValue];

Comment: Is the mutable array nil? The version of the code you've posted works fine.

Comment: Don't use stringWithString here. It's unnecessary.

Comment: it's when I remove stringWithString, I get the error message. also, I lied about the situation a little bit, I'm using a string from a static NSString

Comment: You're getting an error because you didn't put the quotes around cake.

Comment: Your code still works fine for me. Use breakpoints to check if your array is nil.

Comment: idk man I'm testing it over and over, and yea the object is nil... I dunno why it's not adding the static string... i have it typed just like above, and it's either giving an error or being nil. if I type `NSString* dessert = cake;` everything works, but when I put it in the array it crunks, are you sure you are using a static NSString and not just a regular NSString?

Comment: Please provide your code _exactly_ as written.

Comment: NSString does not have a `stringValue` method.

Comment: I can't believe it, but it's true. It even compiled without telling me anything was wrong. I assumed if `integerValue` was used with integers... well, problem is finally solved

Comment: @user3400450: It compiled without any warnings because there *are* objects that respond to `stringValue`, and the compiler didn't know the object was an NSString because `objectAtIndex:` returns `id`.

Comment: Shouldn't he have gotten an unrecognized selector exception?

Comment: @CrimsonChris: And indeed OP got "an exception." They never specified what the exception was.

Comment: That information would have been so helpful.

Comment: Can you just copy paste the exception log which it returns?

Comment: @user3400450 `-integerValue` isn't used with integers (which are usually understood to be of type `int`, `long`, etc.) but rather with `NSString` and `NSNumber` objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely that your array is nil. This code works.

```
NSMutableArray *foodArray = [NSMutableArray array];
[foodArray addObject:@"cake"];
NSString *dessert = foodArray[0]; //dessert is "cake"
```

*Update*

The unrecognized selector exception you are getting is the result of calling `stringValue` on an NSString. As @Chuck noted, NSString does not have that method.